# Python webdriver: reusing setUp and tearDown

Tags: python, oop, automation, webdriver

Hello can you give me example for reusing setUp and tearDown in another class for example

base.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
class Login(object):
  def setUp(self):
  # create a new Firefox session
   self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
   self.driver.get("google.com")
   self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
   self.driver.maximize_window()

  def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()
```

login.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
import base
import unittest

class LoginPage(unittest.TestCase):
 ...how to call setUp() and tearDown() from base.py...
    def test_logn(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('username')
     ...etc...
```

Can you provide example please to run it on pc and see how it works.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `LoginPage` a subclass of `base.Login`, so that it inherits `Login.setUp` and `Login.tearDown`:

base.py

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

class Login(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # create a new Firefox session
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("http://google.com")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
```

login.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
import base
import unittest

class LoginPage(base.Login):

    def test_logn(self):
        elt = self.driver.find_element_by_name('q')
        elt.send_keys('python')
        elt.submit()
        for result in self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('g'):
            print(result.text)
            print('-' * 80)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: when i write python login.py the firefox doesnt start :(

Comment: Does your `login.py` have the `unittest.main()` call at the end?

Comment: One more question is it possible to implement test_login in base.py and in login.py to be another test scenario without closing the browser.

Comment: One of the principles of unit testing is that every test should be independent of every other test.